# How to make a next button using pdo?

Tags: php, pdo

I am working on a project right now, everything works fine the CRUD functions are all working. i have a page of class.user.php, viewsample.php and next.php. now, my problem is this i just want to add a next button inside the viewsample.php, if i clicked on a specific record or id it will show me the records of that person or id in viewsample.php. inside the viewsample.php i want to add a next button because one id or person has lots of details that can't just fit on a single window so, i want to add a next button on it.so that when a user clicked the next button it will display other details of that specific person or id.i dont want want to happen is when i clicked the next button it will go to the next id..what i want is to stay on that current id and show other details of that id or person..can someby please help me?

**class.user.php**

```
public function dataview($query)
{

$stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * from login ORDER BY username");
$stmt->execute();

if($stmt->rowCount()>0)
{
while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td> ".$row['user_id']." </td>";
echo "<td> ".$row['username']." </td>";

echo '<td><a target="_blank" onclick="pop_up(this)" href=VIEWSAMPLE.PHP?user_id='.$row['user_id'].'>'.$row["username"].'</a></td>';

echo "<td> ".$row['password']." </td>";
echo '<td><a style="float:left" target="_blank" href="update.php?user_id=' . $row["user_id"] . '>'.$row["username"].'"<input name="image" type="image" value="edit" onclick="pop_up(this)"><image src="image/EDIT.png" class="img-responsive" width="25px"></a>
<a style="float:left" href="delete.php?user_id=' . $row["user_id"] . '>" <input name="image" type="image" value="delete" onclick="return confirm(\'are you sure?\')"><image src="image/DELETE.png" class="img-responsive" width="25px"></a></td>';
echo "</tr>";
}
}
else
{
 echo "<tr>";
        "<td>Nothing here...</td>";
        "</tr>";
}
}
}
```

viewsample.php

```
<?php
include_once 'dbconfig.php';
$username = isset($_GET['username']) ? $_GET['username'] : '';
$password = isset($_GET['password']) ? $_GET['password'] : '';
$province = isset($_GET['province']) ? $_GET['province'] : '';

if(isset($_GET['user_id']))
{
$user_id = $_GET['user_id'];
extract($crud->getID($user_id));
}
?>

<body>

<a href="NEXT.php?user_id=id FROM login">Next</a>
<br />
<br />

<div id="Survey-view">
    <div id="header">
    </div>

    <p><strong>INFORMATION</strong></p>
        <hr />
            <div id="main-frame">
                <table id="information-content" cellspacing="0">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Username</th>
                            <th>Password</th>
                            <th>Province</th>
                        </tr>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $username; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $password; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $province; ?></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    </thead>
                </table>
            </div>
        <br />
    <br />
```

**next.php**

```
<?php
include_once 'dbconfig.php';
$username = isset($_GET['username']) ? $_GET['username'] : '';
$password = isset($_GET['password']) ? $_GET['password'] : '';
$province = isset($_GET['province']) ? $_GET['province'] : '';

if(isset($_GET['user_id']))
{
$user_id = $_GET['user_id'];
extract($crud->getID($user_id));
}
?>

<p><strong>INFORMATION</strong></p>
        <hr />
            <div id="main-frame">
                <table id="information-content" cellspacing="0">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Username</th>
                            <th>Password</th>
                            <th>Province</th>
                        </tr>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $username; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $password; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $province; ?></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    </thead>
                </table>
            </div>
```

Comment: Password in the query string? Yikes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to use `AJAX` to pull new info on the same user, but depending on how much data there was, you could render out the information all at once and use javascript to hide and show different parts. Maybe something similar to this *(I am using jQuery, because my knowledge of javascript is even less than my ability to use jQuery effectively, and I'm sure someone more adept in jQuery/javascript could do this better)*:

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/qmzj7tsw/

**Styles:**

```
<style>
.default-show   {
display: block !important;
}
.stuff  {
    display: none;
}
.btn-next   {
    cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="btn-next">NEXT</div>
<ul id="userInfo">
    <li class="stuff default-show">Stuff1</li>
    <li class="stuff">Stuff2</li>
    <li class="stuff">Stuff3</li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery:**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".btn-next").click(function() {
        var curr    =   $(".default-show");
        var next    =   curr.next();
        if(next.attr("class") !== 'stuff') {
            var all_btns    =   $("#userInfo").children("li");
            curr.removeClass("default-show");
            curr    =   $(all_btns[0]);
            curr.addClass("default-show");
        }
        else {
            curr.removeClass("default-show");
            curr.next().addClass("default-show");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: but how can i put the values from databse to textbox?

Comment: You just call your data into whatever page you need to and use one page for everything. You don't need a bunch of different pages.

Comment: as you can see in next.php is that what your saying?

Comment: You have the page that contains the users data. You basically have two buttons, one is to load new users, one is to navigate the current user. You load all the current user in to this one page.

Comment: If you need an example, I could probably make one quick enough

Comment: All the colored boxes are buttons. GREEN->Loads new id. ORANGE->toggles through the current user info. RED->Advances to the next user

Comment: i already saw the demo but the problem is that when i press the next id it go to the next record..what i want is that when the next button is press it will go other details of that current id not going to the next id

Comment: oh..i'm sorry my mistake i forgot to press the orange one..that what i', looking for but what is the code for that?

Comment: what i need now to do is just paste your code in my viewsample.php and edit it with mine?

Comment: Yes but you need to understand the end product before you start copying and pasting